# Error in Converting PyTorch Model to ONNX format

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, tflite

I want to convert `https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN` to ONNX format to use in Android App. After going through the procedure, it shows error (AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'modules').

Following is my code in Colab:

```
!pip install onnx

!pip install torch torchvision onnx
import urllib.request

url = "https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/releases/download/v0.2.0/GFPGANCleanv1-NoCE-C2.pth"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "my_model.pth")
```

```
import torch
import numpy as np

model = torch.load("my_model.pth")

input_shape = (1, 3, 224, 224)
example_input = torch.rand(input_shape)
```

```
import urllib.request
import torch

output_path = "my_model.onnx"
torch.onnx.export(model, input_shape, output_path, opset_version=11)

# Load and check the ONNX model for correctness
onnx_model = onnx.load(output_path)
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
```

Here in the last code snippet the following error is shown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ef0dbdcd2de8> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 output_path = "my_model.onnx"
----> 5 torch.onnx.export(model, input_shape, output_path, opset_version=11)
      6 
      7 # Load and check the ONNX model for correctness

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py in disable_apex_o2_state_dict_hook(model)
    137     if not isinstance(model, torch.jit.ScriptFunction):
    138         model_hooks = {}  # type: ignore[var-annotated]
--> 139         for module in model.modules():
    140             for key, hook in module._state_dict_hooks.items():
    141                 if type(hook).__name__ == "O2StateDictHook":

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

I tried to convert the model into ONNX and imported libraries. But the issue comes while exporting the torch.onnx.export.

Answer (score 1):

Use the torch2onnx.py file of the following repository to convert to onnx. You can find both onnx conversion code and inference code there. I have converted GFPGAN from pth to onnx using the code and it executed without any errors. And also no problem in inferencing.

https://github.com/xuanandsix/GFPGAN-onnxruntime-demo